# Firestore get() all documents in a collection returns an error

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to iterate all the documents in the collection with the get() method as defined in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection), however it doesn't work for me. I get a `get is not a function` error, what am I doing wrong?

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
    selectedCharacter: number = null;
    people: Observable<any>;
    private peopleCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Character>;

    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore,
          private route: ActivatedRoute,
          private location: Location) {
      this.peopleCollection = db.collection('people');
      this.people = this.peopleCollection.valueChanges();

      this.route.params.subscribe(
          params => (this.selectedCharacter = +params['id'])
      );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.peopleCollection.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            });
        });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR : this.peopleCollection.***ref***.get()

The collection method `valueChanges` returns an `Observable` :

```
export declare class AngularFirestoreCollection<T> {
    ...
    valueChanges(events?: DocumentChangeType[]): Observable<T[]>;
    ...
}
```

You could subscrible to the `Observable` returned by `valueChanges` :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.people.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Or you can use the `CollectionReference` to get the `Promise`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.peopleCollection.ref.get().then(data => console.log(data));
}
```